# Method evaluation not behaving as expected

Tags: scala

Below code calculates the total a fibonacci sequence to a particular number.

But a StackOverFlow exception is being thrown. Why is this exception being thrown as I am checking 
for 0 within the function ?

```
object fibonacci extends Application {

def fibonacci(i : Int) : Int = {
    println(i)
    if(i == 0) 0
    if(i == 1) 1
    fibonacci(i - 1) + fibonacci(i - 2)
}

fibonacci(3)

}
```

Error :

```
scala> fibonacci(3)
3
2
1
0
-1
-2
-3
-4
-5
-6
-7
-8
-9
.......


scala> fibonacci(3)
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at .fibonacci(<console>:10)
        at .fibonacci(<console>:10)
        at .fibonacci(<console>:10)
        at .fibonacci(<console>:10)
```

Comment: Maybe change the title to "evaluation of my method...".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def fibonacci(i : Int) : Int = {
    println(i)
    if (i == 0) 0
    else if (i == 1) 1
    else fibonacci(i - 1) + fibonacci(i - 2)
}
```

Without those `else` you're not stopping when you reach 0 or 1.

Answer (score 2):

Scala will automatically evaluate the return value of a function to be the value of the last statement calculated (this is the reason you don't need the `return` keyword).

Without `else`s, your two `if` statements are stand-alone statements, but not the last statement in the function. They resolve to a value, but this value is not assigned to anything and so is thrown away and the function continues processing statements.

Putting `else`s in (as per @Marth's solution) ensures that you end the function with one single statement consisting of a single if-else chain. This whole statement (and hence, the function) evaluates to the result of whichever branch of the chain is selected and executed.

You can also acheive the effect you want using a `match` (which is also treated as one single statement):

```
def fibonacci(i : Int) : Int = {
    println(i)
    i match {
        case 0 => 0
        case 1 => 1
        case _ => fibonacci(i - 1) + fibonacci(i - 2)
    }
}
```